# Loading a wave from waveid

Tags: python, google-wave

I'm working on a small wave thingy where i need to load a wave based on an outside event. So i don't have a context to work with.

I've been looking at the python api for a while but i can't figure out the correct way to get a wave object (that i can then call CreateBlip() on) when i just have the waveid.

Is there something i've just overlooked? or do I have to make a 'raw' json request instead of using the api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Google I/O, the [Wave Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/wavedataapi/index.html) was announced which allows for pulling waves which haven't previously gotten a context as long as they're accessible to a @googlewave.com user authenticated through OAuth. However, this can not call CreateBlip()

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the answer is that i can't be done. Hopefully in a future version of the Api.